GCP IAP + AppLb + cloud run No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error
we have a problem with such configuration GCP IAP + Global external Application Load Balancer + cloud run.
After closing browser getting
Access to script at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?login_hint=***' (redirected from 'https://staging.domain.co.uk/assets/index-hH-TJnqz.js') from origin 'https://staging.domain.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

On cloud we have server configured according this article with enabled cors - cloud-run-iap
On IAP level also enabled this setting
HTTP Options
Also tried to add the crossorigin="use-credentials" attribute to the site manifest's link element, without success.
And tried this config for IAP
gcloud beta iap settings set iap.yaml --project=staging --resource-type=compute --service=staging-dashboard-lb-backend
accessSettings:
  allowedDomainsSettings:
    domains:
    - staging.domain.co.uk
    enable: true
  corsSettings:
    allowHttpOptions: true

When IAP disabled we don't see such errors. Please help, I can share any additional info if needed
